# How to fix code so output is either a palindrome or not

Tags: java, loops, palindrome

I am trying to write a program that reads a file containing a list of words, and will tell the user if the word is a palindrome or not. Where am I going wrong with this code? 
The output says they are all palindromes, which they are not.

I have tried changing the loops. I am starting to think it may be the while loop, but I need this to scan the file.

```
  File file = new File("dictionary.txt");
  Scanner INPUT = new Scanner(file); 

  while (INPUT.hasNextLine()) {      

         String forward = INPUT.nextLine(); String reverseText = forward;

        for(int i = forward.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        reverseText += forward.charAt(i);

    if (reverseText.equals(forward))     
        System.out.println(forward + " is a palindrome");        
    else    
        System.out.println(forward + " is not a palindrome");
    }
```

I have watched some youtube videos and read a lot of code snippets. I am new to Java, but it seems the palindrome code is correct. So is it the reading of the file that is the problem?

Comment: `String reverseText = forward;` must be `String reverseText = "";`

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me the same result:alindrome problem.
passerby is not a palindrome
absobloominglutely  is not a palindrome
nana  is not a palindrome
banana  is not a palindrome
the  is not a palindrome
jumps  is not a palindrome
over  is not a palindrome
the  is not a palindrome
lazy  is not a palindrom
a  is not a palindrome
mm  is not a palindrome
noon  is not a palindrome
radar  is not a palindrome
redder  is not a palindrome
racecar  is not a palindrome
redivider  is not a palindrome
tattarrattat  is not a palindrome
Goodbye!

Comment: All level tip: learn and use *debugging*, you won't need help again 

Comment: @Peta Really? Because if I change just what user7 said, and try all the words you listed in the comment, then it seems to work fine. See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/kl7VCt) for proof.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be fixed, but I'd argue that it's a bad algorithm and should be replaced.  You have a space inefficiency in that you *don't* need to create an entire reversed string.  And you have a time inefficiency in that the word is known to not be a palidrome as soon as there's a letter mismatch, all further processing is wasted time.  Consider instead:

```
File file = new File("dictionary.txt");
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

outer: while (input.hasNextLine())
{
    String word = input.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim();

    for (int i = 0, j = word.length() - 1; j > i; i++, j--)
    {
        if (word.charAt(i) != word.charAt(j))
        {
            System.out.println(word + " is not a palindrome");
            continue outer;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(word + " is a palindrome");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the first variable to an empty string then add to it. Also, you will need to make the input string lowercase otherwise the equals comparison will take into account uppercase characters(ie Redder ≠ reddeR). Another thing to consider is removing whitespace(space and tabs at the end of a string) as it will ruin the comparison.

```
        File file = new File("dictionary.txt");
        Scanner INPUT = new Scanner(file);

        while (INPUT.hasNextLine()) {

            String forward = INPUT.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim();
            String reverseText = "";

            for(int i = forward.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                reverseText += forward.charAt(i);

            if (reverseText.equals(forward))
                System.out.println(forward + " is a palindrome");
            else
                System.out.println(forward + " is not a palindrome");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, I have been stuck on this for a while.